# Access shadowed variable from anonymous class

Tags: java

I have a static function that takes a parameter called X.

In this static function I create an anonymous class.  This class should have a member variable, also called X.

From the functions in the anonymous class, how can I access the function's parameter X?

To illustrate:

```
class Test {

    static void func(final List<T> X) {

        new Test() {
            final T[] X = ?.X.toArray();
        };
    }
}
```

In my real code I want to create an array in my anonymous class from a list argument (via `toArray()` in the anonymous class's initialisation), and I want to re-use the same variable name rather than using hungarian notation to differentiate them.

Comment: Why don't you add another variable called something else that is not 'X' inside the static function, and then call it from the anonymous class?

Comment: @m1o2 yes but it is the large number of variables with near same name that just denote alternative data-types that I'm trying to clean up.  My code would be much cleaner if I could change the type of a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible in Java. Function parameters have no "namespace" like `this` which you could use to denote which variable you mean.

The only solution is to create an arbitrary prefix like `outerX` for the outer parameter or `xAsArray` for the inner.